# SQL Query to show all columns

Tags: sql

I have the following table and a SQL query to determine if any items in a table have a buy price higher than a sell price.

[image]

Query:

```
SELECT id, name 
FROM orders 
GROUP BY id, name 
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN buy = 'false' THEN price END) > MIN(CASE WHEN buy = 'true' THEN price END)
```

The problem is that this only returns two rows:

[image]

The result I am looking for should show all the items that have a buy price higher than a sell price with all the columns. Reading up on `GROUP BY` I see that it only returns distinct values. Do I have to use joins to achieve the end result?

```
|id  |buy   |date                    |price |name
 --------------------------------------------------
 3    false  2017-01-04 19:23:12.000  7      bread
 3    false  2017-01-04 19:23:12.000  4      bread
 2    false  2017-01-04 19:23:12.000  7      grapes
```

Using this query the result is the table below the rows highlighted in red shouldn't be there.

```
SELECT * 
FROM orders 
WHERE id IN (SELECT id 
             FROM orders 
             GROUP BY id, name 
             HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN buy = 'false'  THEN price END) > MIN(CASE WHEN  buy = 'true' THEN price END))
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried adding the other columns to the query. I updated post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your existing query as a subquery:

```
SELECT * from orders where id in 
(
    SELECT id 
    FROM orders 
    GROUP BY id, name 
    HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN buy = 'false'  THEN price END) > MIN(CASE WHEN buy = 'true' THEN price END)
)
```

Comment: Hi Fauxmosapien for answering I added a where clause to your query and the result is correct many thanks for helping.